# Keyboard model for Bilingual Dell laptop

Tags: keyboard, xkb

My keyboard model doesn't match the one used by the system and thus the key above the enter key doesn't work as it should. This happened after I had to "reset" my `~/.config` folder to solve another issue.

This is the keyboard layout in Gnome:
[image]

And this is my actual physical keyboard:
[image]

I tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but I'm at a loss on what layout to set. Furthermore, I don't remember changing this when I first installed Ubuntu.

How to I set it so that the key above the Enter key works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem was not the Keyboard model, even if this was not correct, but the Keyboard layout variant that I had chosen. I replaced the keyboard layout with the correct one and even though the keyboard model shown on the layout preview was (and is) not correct, the keys work as expected.